# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headerCell')

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I need to add a a column button where the user can delete and element. In my ts I do:

```
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Search>;
listResult: Search[];
ngOnInit()
  this.displayedColumns: string[]= ["Id,"remove"];
```

when I do search()

```
 this.searchSevice.getResult(...).subscribe((resultResponse) => {

     
          this.listResult=returnArray(resultResponse);

          this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Search>(this.listResult);
}
```

My button html is:

the problem is that program it gives me :

```
main.aadf78b221195843.js:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headerCell')
    at N.extractCellTemplate (main.aadf78b221195843.js:1:3748019)
    at main.aadf78b221195843.js:1:3764947
    at Function.from (<anonymous>)
    at N._getCellTemplates (main.aadf78b221195843.js:1:3764881)
    at N._renderCellTemplateForItem (main.aadf78b221195843.js:1:3764373)
    at N._renderRow (main.aadf78b221195843.js:1:3764289)
    at main.aadf78b221195843.js:1:3763154
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at N._forceRenderHeaderRows (main.aadf78b221195843.js:1:3763134)
    at N.ngAfterContentChecked (main.aadf78b221195843.js:1:3757447)

main.aadf78b221195843.js:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headerCell')
    at N.extractCellTemplate (main.aadf78b221195843.js:1:3748019)
    at main.aadf78b221195843.js:1:3764947
    at Function.from (<anonymous>)
    at N._getCellTemplates (main.aadf78b221195843.js:1:3764881)
    at N._renderCellTemplateForItem (main.aadf78b221195843.js:1:3764373)
    at N._renderRow (main.aadf78b221195843.js:1:3764289)
    at main.aadf78b221195843.js:1:3763154
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at N._forceRenderHeaderRows (main.aadf78b221195843.js:1:3763134)
    at N.ngAfterContentChecked (main.aadf78b221195843.js:1:3757447)
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: please add your template snippet

Answer (score 1):

For me this was happen when making a mistake in typing. In **typescript** file the display array has element **contractorName** as:

`displayedColumns: string[] = ['contractorName', ...];`

but in the **html** file, by mistake I typed **customerName** instead of **contractorName** for headerCell as:

```
 <ng-container matColumnDef="customerName">
   <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Contractor Name</mat-header-cell>
   <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.contractorName}} </mat-cell>
 </ng-container>
```

I think the problem for you is the uppercase **Id** in `this.displayedColumns: string[]= ["Id,"remove"];` check it in the **html** file.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible the error comes not from the table itself.
For me it was a mistake in *ngFor.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).